# Adding fragment destroys activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, containers

I have an Activity with a container being a FrameLayout. I need to add a fragment to that container, but doing so throws an IllegalStateException, destroying my Activity.

This is my container in the activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/seeMoreContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

This is how I add the fragment to the activity

```
PlacesSeeMoreFragment placesSeeMoreFragment = new PlacesSeeMoreFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(PlacesSeeMoreFragment.KEY, poiID);
placesSeeMoreFragment.setArguments(bundle);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.seeMoreContainer, 
placesSeeMoreFragment).commit();
```

And this is the logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1515)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:634)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:613)
                                                                   at net.ilb.Activities.PlacesActivity.openPlaceSeeMore(PlacesActivity.java:140)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I add the fragment to the activity from a public method, which I call from onItemClickListener of a ListView

This is the whole method

```
public void openPlaceSeeMore(int poiID){
    PlacesSeeMoreFragment placesSeeMoreFragment = new PlacesSeeMoreFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(PlacesSeeMoreFragment.KEY, poiID);
    placesSeeMoreFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.seeMoreContainer, placesSeeMoreFragment).commit();
}
```

And this is how the method is called

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            PlacesActivity placesActivity = new PlacesActivity();
            placesActivity.openPlaceSeeMore(poi.getId());
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is this line PlacesActivity.java:140?

Comment: @k0sh It's this line: 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.seeMoreContainer, 
placesSeeMoreFragment).commit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are calling this:

```
PlacesActivity placesActivity = new PlacesActivity();
```

This is a very wrong approach to call a method declared in activity.
Which is creating new instance of your activity every time you click something on the list. Plus if you want to capture list clicks you should use an interface and not use activity objects anywhere.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code....

```
 Fragment fragment = new PlacesSeeMoreFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                ft.commit();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt(PlacesSeeMoreFragment.KEY, poiID);                  
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: The same exception is being thrown.

Comment: Use ActivityName.this instead of getActivity in code.

Comment: Using doing this did not change anything, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime I faced the same issue and this is what I did. Use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead of `commit()`. Try this one

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.seeMoreContainer, placesSeeMoreFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: It still throws the same exception even with commitAllowingStateLoss().

Answer (score -1):

try this ,

```
    PlacesSeeMoreFragment placesSeeMoreFragment = new PlacesSeeMoreFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(PlacesSeeMoreFragment.KEY, poiID);
    placesSeeMoreFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.add(R.id.seeMoreContainer, placesSeeMoreFragment );
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: After overriding onDetach of the fragment, the same exception is being thrown. Shouldn't it catch it and throw RuntimeException instead?

Comment: The updated answer is basically what I'm doing, though you define a fragment manager and transaction instead of directly using them.